# Need to unset PYTHONPATH every time when I want to use python3 from multiple python versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, centos7, pythonpath

I have multiple python versions installed into my Centos7.

```sh
[root@madcodlab-centos7 ~]# python
Python 2.7.16 (default, May 24 2019, 21:44:39)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

```sh
[root@madcodlab-centos7 ~]# python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But I cannot access python3 normally. Before I access python3 I always have to set ***unset PYTHONPATH*** but it doesn't fix my problem permanently. After I logged out from my vps and log in again I can not access python3. It looks it just a temporary fix. Here is the error when I want to access python3

```sh
[root@madcodlab-centos7 ~]# python3                                                                                                                                               
Error processing line 1 of /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zope.interface-4.6.0-py3.6-nspkg.pth:                                                                         

Failed to import the site module                                                                                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site.py", line 168, in addpackage                                                                                                                    
    exec(line)                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/types.py", line 171, in <module>                                                                                                                     
    import functools as _functools                                                                                                                                                
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/functools.py", line 21, in <module>                                                                                                                  
    from collections import namedtuple                                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>                                                                                                       
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reprlib/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>                                                                                                
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '                                                                                                       
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                               

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site.py", line 564, in <module>                                                                                                                      
    main()                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site.py", line 551, in main                                                                                                                          
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)                                                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site.py", line 339, in addsitepackages                                                                                                               
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)                                                                                                                                              
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site.py", line 207, in addsitedir                                                                                                                    
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site.py", line 178, in addpackage                                                                                                                    
    import traceback                                                                                                                                                              
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/traceback.py", line 3, in <module>                                                                                                                   
    import collections                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>                                                                                                       
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reprlib/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>                                                                                                
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '                                                                                                       
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
```

I tried to solve this by using ***virtualenv***

```sh
sudo pip install virtualenv --upgrade
virtualenv -p python3 env
```

but in my case doesn't solve the problem.

What can I do to fix it permanently?

thanks

Comment: So, `PYTHONPATH= python3` does not work?

Comment: where ? in .bash_profile ?

Comment: No, in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Env is the way to go ...

But you could just type **python3** *fred.py*  - and things then should be ok also

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to fix it by commenting out `export PYTHONPATH` command in $HOME/.bashrc file.